# How to get config vars in Rails Application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to get all config variables but I do not quite understand something about Rails config...

Let's say, I have something like `config.myvar` in test.rb, and when running I do:

```
MyApp::Application.config.myvar           # works
MyApp::Application.config.send("myvar")   # works as well
```

If I'm correct, I can assume it is a function, as specified in the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send). Yet, calling `methods` will give me (a lot of) methods but not mine...
Same as [`instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) or anything I could try.

There is obviously something I miss, if you have any clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not now how this mechanism work when I read your question (although I had a pretty good idea.) This is how I figured it out, reading the source code to rails:

The Rails Application configuration is found in rails under rails/railties/lib/rails/application.rb in the rails source. We can see it creates a configuration object like so:

```
def config #:nodoc:
  @config ||= Application::Configuration.new(find_root_with_flag("config.ru", Dir.pwd))
end
```

So we can chase down `Application::Configuration` in rails/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb.

However, this is a fairly small class with nothing that allows calling arbitrary methods. Let's go up the chain. This is a child of `::Rails::Engine::Configuration`, so let's go to this file. (rails/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb if you're following correctly).

Again, a fairly small class with a defined set of functions. However, this has a parent class too! `::Rails::Railtie::Configuration`. So we look at the source of this file (rails/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration):

And right there at the end, we have the ever popular [#method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb#L89):

```
  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    if name.to_s =~ /=$/
      @@options[$`.to_sym] = args.first
    elsif @@options.key?(name)
      @@options[name]
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Reading this, we see if the name includes an `=`, we set the class variable option hash to equal the first argument, with the name of the method you called as the key (after symbolizing it). Otherwise, we return the content of the that key in the options hash. However, because it works this way, neither `#methods` or `#instance_variables` works. However, once again, reading this file, we see rails gives us an option:

```
  def respond_to?(name)
    super || @@options.key?(name.to_sym)
  end
```

This will return true if the key has been set.

To get a list, you could:

```
MyApp::Application.config.class_variable_get(:@@options).keys
```

which will give you a list of keys in the options class variable

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly via `MyApp::Application.config.class_eval { class_variable_get :@@options }`